# Context Not Printing Django

Tags: python, django

I'm aware my issue may be to lack of Django knowledge, but I'm trying to pass user input from one form in a view, to another view which will then render that view's HTML page with the given input.

I'm redirected fine, but the data is not being displayed. I believe it has something to do with the contexts not being passed properly, but I do not understand what is wrong or how to fix it.

`views.py`

```
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
    print(request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form2 = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid():
            post = form2.save(commit=False)
            post.poster = request.user
            post.content = form2.cleaned_data.get('content')
            post.title = form2.cleaned_data.get('title')
            post.syntax = form2.cleaned_data.get('syntax')
            post.public = form2.cleaned_data.get('public')
            rand = str(uuid.uuid4())[:6]
            while Paste.objects.filter(generated_url=rand):
                rand = str(uuid.uuid4())[:6]
            post.generated_url = rand
            form2.save()
            context = {
                "poster_name": post.poster,
                "paste_contents": post.content,
                "paste_title": post.title,
                "paste_syntax": post.syntax,
                "paste_visible": post.public
            }
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('details', args=(post.generated_url,)), context)
    else:
        form2 = PostForm()

    return render(request, "home.html", {'form2': form2})
def detail_view(request, *args, **kwargs):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method=='POST':
            form3 = PostForm(request.POST)
            url = form3.generated_url
            your_posts = Paste.objects.get(url)
            context = {
                'form3': form3
            }
            return render(request, "paste_detail.html", context)

    return render(request, "paste_detail.html", {'form3': form3})
```

`home.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Your user is {{ request.user }}</h1>
<div class="submit_form">
<form action="" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form2.as_p }}<br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Paste" id="submit">
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

And `paste_detail.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<!--<h1>Name of post: {{ post.title }}</h1>-->

<p>Content of post:</p>
I AM REDIRECTED
<h1>Name of post: {{ form2.title }}</h1>

<p>Content of post:</p>

<p>{{form3.content|linebreaks}}</p>
{{ form3.poster }}
{{ form3.contents }}
{{ form3.title }}
{{ form3.syntax }}
{{ form3.visible }}
{% endblock %}
```

edit:

`views.py`

```
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form2 = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid():
            post = form2.save(commit=False)
            post.poster = request.user
            post.save()
            rand = str(uuid.uuid4())[:6]
            while Paste.objects.filter(generated_url=rand):
                rand = str(uuid.uuid4())[:6]
            post.generated_url = rand
        #    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('details', args=(post.generated_url,)), context)
            return redirect('detail', rand)
    else:
        form2 = PostForm()

    return render(request, "home.html", {'form2': form2})
def detail_view(request, custom_uuid):

    post = get_object_or_404(Paste, pk=pk)
    return render(request, "paste_detail.html", {'post': post})
    #return render(request, "paste_detail.html", {'form3': form3})
```

`paste_detail.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}


<p>Content of post:</p>
I AM REDIRECTED

<h1>Name of post: {{ post.title }}</h1>



<p>Creator of post:</p> {{ post.poster }}
<p>Content of post:</p> {{ post.content }}
<p>Title of post:</p> {{ post.title }}
{{ post.syntax }}
{{ post.visible }}
{% endblock %}
```

And `urls.py`

```
...
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', home_view, name='home'),
    path('contact/', contact_view, name='contact'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
    path('about/', about_view, name='about'),
    url(r'^signup/$', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('paste_list/', paste_list_view, name='paste_list'),
    url(r'^$', home_view),
    #url(r'^(?P<rand_url>\S{6})/$', detail_view, name='details'),
    path('detail/<str:custom_uuid>/', detail_view, name='detail'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Is the template named `page_detail.html` or `paste_detail.html`?

Comment: @JohnGordon`paste_detail.html` Sorry for the typo I'll fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your code. Lets fix them one by one(Please check the code comments for explanation):

In `home_view` you are doing some redundant codes, you can simplify like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

...
if request.method == 'POST':
    form2 = PostForm(request.POST)
    if form2.is_valid():
        post = form2.save(commit=False)  # it is not saved in db
        post.poster = request.user
        rand = str(uuid.uuid4())[:6]
        while Paste.objects.filter(generated_url=rand).exists():
            rand = str(uuid.uuid4())[:6]
        post.generated_url = rand
        post.save()  # it will save all information to DB, so you don't need to call form2.cleaned_data.get(..)

       return redirect('details', custom_uuid=rand)  # I am redirecting to `detail_view`. here `rand` is the random uuid of the post which is saved in db
else:
    form2 = PostForm()

return render(request, "home.html", {'form2': form2})  # rendering form for GET request
```

Now lets update detail view to catch the [redirection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def detail_view(request, custom_uuid):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, generated_url=custom_uuid)  # getting the post object from database using model. 
    return render(request, "post_detail.html", {'post': post})  # sending data in context to template

# url
path('detail/<str:custom_uuid>/', detail_view, name='detail')  # here <str:custom_uuid> will catch the uuid sent in the url

# HTML
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<p>Content of post:</p>
I AM REDIRECTED
<h1>Name of post: {{ post.title }}</h1>  // <-- getting this context from view

<p>Content of post:</p>

<p>{{post.content|linebreaks}}</p>
{{ post.poster }}
{{ post.contents }}
{{ post.title }}
{{ post.syntax }}
{{ post.visible }}
{% endblock %}
```

Here [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) gets the entry for model `Post`, if its not found then throws 404 error.

Comment: That does make sense. If however, I wanted to not use a URL structure such as `webapp.com/detail/pkid` and rather wanted to use `webapp.com/generated_url` how would I alter the code to reflect this? In my `views.py` you can see I am creating a random string by doing 

`            rand = str(uuid.uuid4())[:6]
            while Paste.objects.filter(generated_url=rand):
                rand = str(uuid.uuid4())[:6]
            post.generated_url = rand`

Comment: You can pass the UUID generated in `generated_url`. You can use `path('detail/<str:custom_uuid>/'...)` and catch that uuid in the view using `def detail(request, custom_uuid):..`

Comment: I may not be following you correctly. I am changing the return to `return redirect('detail', rand)` in the home view, changing the detail_view def to `def detail_view(request, custom_uuid)` and the url.py to have `path('detail/<str:custom_uuid>/', detail_view, name='detail'),` ?

I will edit my OP for easier readability, please have a look. Thank you.

Comment: @NickM I have updated my answer. please have a look.

Comment: for some reason I am getting a `No Paste matches the given query.` error when trying to submit from the home page.

Comment: It is hard to say where the problem occurred. Can you please add the stacktrace in question?

Answer (score 2):

Contexts are per-request. Once your view has returned, the context no longer exists. When you do a redirect, you are finishing that request/response cycle and starting another one with your `detail` view. None of the context will carry over.

Instead, you need a way to store pertinent information between requests. One fairly simple way to do this is storing data in the *session*.

For example, you might store `title` in a session like this in `home_view`:

```
request.session['title'] = post.title
```

And then in your `detail_view` view, you could add it to your context:

```
context = {
    'title': request.session.get('title')
}
```

Check out the Django documentation on sessions for more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: Using sessions makes sense. I am lost syntactically on how to proceed. Do you mind providing an example of one of the fields so I can better understand?

Comment: No problem. See my updated answer. You may still need to check out the docs to make sure you have a session store set up correctly (though I _think_ this is done by default if you still have the default Django settings.

Comment: I'll look into this. Thanks so much!